# How do you get the same web response error message as Postman in VB?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, postman

For example, I run a POST request in Postman that I know has an expired token and I get this: [image: Postman error]

In my Visual Studio project, I am building the same request, but the WebException object doesn't have any of the "TokenError" details, only "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

So my question is: Is there a way to get the same error details in .NET as in Postman?

Comment: Have you actually read the ResponseStream from the WebException object's Response?

Comment: @Jimi - It creates an exception when it sees the 417 header for me. I told it to not expect 100 to continue, but it still comes back as an exception, and when I try to trap for it, the response isn't there because it errored out.  I, too, want to grab the actual service message when I get a 417 http error.